# Is the number of unique values in a matrix bounded by the product of the corresponding statistic for rows and columns?

Tags: combinatorics, inequality

Suppose we have an $r\times c$ matrix of natural numbers, $M$.

Suppose also that the number of unique values in any given row is at most $n$, and the number of unique values in any given column is at most $m$.

Can we show that the number of unique values in $M$ is at most $mn$?

This seems so trivial that I'm almost too embarrassed to ask, but having just spent an hour failing to get various induction schemes to work, I have caved in. Please show me what I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's correct when $m=1$ or $n=1$, but already for $m=n=2$ one can get as many different numbers as desired, by the following scheme:

$$\begin{array}{ccc}
2 & 1 & 1 & 1 & \ldots \\
1 & 3 & 1 & 1 & \ldots \\
1 & 1 & 4 & 1 & \ldots \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 5 & \ldots \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots \\
\end{array}$$

Comment: Thank you, I am a fool! :facepalm:

Comment: As always, even though the counterexample may be simple, it took some time to get there, so don't feel foolish ;-)

Comment: Good advice, thanks again :-)